# Do I have to post objects seperately with Angular 7 and Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, angular, http-post

I am trying to post objects to my server but the received objects have the value null.

Backend Code:

```
// Signature 

public IActionResult Save(string num, string pat, string token, [FromBody]DataCl data, [FromBody]List<items> listItems)

// EDIT: Added class
    public class Object
    {
        public List<items> listItems { get; set; }
        public DataCl data { get; set; }
    }

// So new signature
public IActionResult Save(string num, string pat, string token, [FromBody]Test test)
// The value is still null
```

Frontend Code:

```
post(num, data, list)
 return this.http.post<any>(url,{data, list}, httpOptions).subscribe()
```

So the parameter num, pat and token are receiving the correct data but the data representing the body are not reciving any data - they are null.

With only one object it is working fine - the correct object was received but with two it does not work anymore but why? Is it something in the frontend code? Or backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method.
>   The ASP.NET Core runtime delegates the responsibility of reading the
>   request stream to the input formatter. Once the request stream is
>   read, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other
>   [FromBody] parameters.

You cannot have two `FromBody` attributes. The from body is only read once.

`{data, list}` is one object anyway in javascript. There is no way to Post multiple objects in body, unless they are embedded.

```
{
   object1: {}
   object2: {}
}
```

And in you backend code:

```
class WrapperObjectResponse {
    public Object1 = ...
    public Object2 = ...
}
```

In your new signature, try this:

```
[Route("save/{num}/{pat}/{token}")]
public IActionResult Save(string num, string pat, string token, [FromBody]Test test)
```

And call like this:

```
return this.http.post<any>(url + '/' + num + '/' + pat + '/' + token + '/',{data: {}, list = []}, httpOptions).subscribe()
```

Comment: So the frontend code is correct since ```{data, list} <=> {data: {}, list: [{}] ```. So one object and an array of objects, is this a correct form to post?

Comment: Absolutely. But you will need to make the appropriate changes to your backend class to accept a data property and list.

Comment: Maybe you can help me again: I have the class Test: ```class Test { public data Data; public List<Items> ListItems;}``` ? The signature is also changed to [FromBody]Test, but the value is still null but why?

Comment: What is your signature in asp.net? Can you edit the question to add the changed code?

Comment: I did. I would appreciate it if you look over it.